# Convert javascript value to binary to be placed into mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, binary

I have a column in my `mysql` table of type `binary`(`password`). Within my object:

```
{
    password: request.password
};
```

Each value in the object is a `string`. How do I convert the value for `password` to binary to be placed into the mysql row?

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| password   | binary(16)   | NO   | PRI |                   |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Comment: [OWASP Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @Andreas I'm going to add some encrpytion to my passwords but I also want to convert these values to binary to performance reasons

Answer (score 1):

```js
var password = "test";
var result = "";
var i = password.length;
while (i--) {
  result += (password.charCodeAt(i) >>> 0).toString(2);
}
console.log(result);
```